# Angular2 trigger function when observable property changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-changedetection

I use a `workingData` service that holds data that permeates my application. It returns an observable to the Mock `workingData` object.

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkingDataService {
  getWorkingData(): Observable<WorkingData> {
    return Observable.of(WORKINGDATA);
  }
  getSelectedDate(): Observable<Date> {
    return Observable.of(WORKINGDATA.selectedDate);
  }
}
```

One property on the `workingData` object is a date field called `selectedDate`.

```
export const WORKINGDATA: WorkingData = {
  today: new Date(),
  selectedDate: new Date('11-15-2016'),
  targetDate: new Date(),
  data: []
};
```

This value can be updated by clicking the "previous month" or "next month" buttons:
[image]

This triggers the following function (or it's `incrementDate()` counterpart) in the `cal-nav` component:

```
decrementDate(): void {
  let newDate = new Date(this.workingData.selectedDate.getDate());
  newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() - 1);
  this.workingData.monthPrior = newDate;
}
```

The observable updates the view in all comopnents in  which the `workingDate` service is injected, but I now need to trigger a funtion in the `month` component (which is a sibling of the `cal-nav` component). **How trigger a function in the `month` componenet each time `workingData.selectedDate` is updated, even if it is updated from a different component?**

UPDATE: I now subscribe to the `selectedDate` property seperately.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getWorkingData();
  this.getSelectedDate(); // Just added
}

getSelectedDate(): void{
  this._workingDataService.getSelectedDate().subscribe(selectedDate => {this.myFunc();});
}
myFunc(){
  console.log('working');
}
```

This fires `myFunc()` oninit but not when the the value updates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just subscribe to your Observable in your code

```
this.myObservable.subscribe( data => {
  myFunction();
 });
```

If that does not fulfil your needs then you have to provide more code or some sequence of what you exactly need

Comment: I don't want to trigger the function unless that specific property changes, not the whole object. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes observe that property separately.

Comment: is this sufficient?

Comment: Create an observable holding your property und subscribe to it

Comment: I thought I had done that `getSelectedDate()`. How must I change my code? see my update service

Comment: Better create a variable in your service if type Observable<Date> and call myVar.next(someDate) whenever you update your date. And return that variable in getSelectedDate() of your service. Or you call Observable next() on your whole data but  each time your date changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130054/discussion-between-nate-may-and-lastwhisper).